# User permissions from HABTM relationship

Tags: cakephp, authentication, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a `'User'` model which is related to a `'Group'` model via HABTM relationship. I am able to query the model to determine which memberships the authenticated user belongs to but am unable to conceptually come up with a method of easily accessing that data on a page's `isAuthorized()` function call.

Ideally I'm hoping there's a way I can link into the authentication method and cache the authorized user's group memberships so I can do a quick lookup on `isAuthorized()` calls. Is there some functionality in cake that would allow this? I'm obviously open to recommendations as I am fairly new to the framework after inheriting this project from a past employee.

From what I've been able to gather is that I would want to be able to access or search the group memberships of the user returned by `AuthComponent::user()` but since that's a static method I don't get access to its Model. Is this possible?

**EDIT**:
Solution was a mixture of the discussion I had with ndm as well as finding out that the application seemed to break authentication. This might be the fault of the last dev who created the application but I managed to resolve it by overriding part of the `BaseAuthenticate`.`_findUser($username,$password)` function to inherit the 'Group' Array along with the 'User' array. It was being fetched on login but only the 'User' portion of the model returned back to the Controller that called Auth.

Comment: You are using Cake 2.x, right? Are you trying to implement a [custom authorization object](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects)?

Comment: I am using 2.x but would not think this is a custom object. The user authentication I am using works fine and achieves all my goals except for the group memberships. I need some way of having global access to the 'User' model in a way where I can query the user's groups in any controller.

Comment: Ah, ok, so what you need is, from within any controller, retreive the groups of the currently logged in user?

Comment: Correct. The lookup I can do on `UsersController` with `find()` works there but wont be something I can do globally from Controllers I use that don't link to the User model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retreiving the groups of the currently logged in user should be simple, you'd just need to configure your [authentication handler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) appropriately so that it fetches the associated models. This can be done using the [resurive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive) or [contain](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) setting, though the latter seems to be kinda broken currently (at least the behaviour is unexpected).

Example using `recursive`:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array
(
    'Form' => array
    (
        'userModel' => 'User',
        'recursive' => 1
    )
);
```

Example using `contain`:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array
(
    'Form' => array
    (
        'userModel' => 'User',
        'contain' => array('Group')
    )
);
```

In order for the `contain` method to work, the `User` model needs to act as [`Containable`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)! However, as mentioned, this seems to be broken, because [`recursive` is always used](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/bf628c493c1869c7c7d25d7298043e6b13f28179/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php#L87), and it's not possible to set it to `null` because it's being casted to an integer. So you'd need to supply the appropriate `recursive` setting too (ie recursive = 1), however this somehow defeats the purpose of the `Containable` behaviour which should figure out the appropriate recursive setting automatically (unless configured otherwise).

Anyway, both would make the authenticator fetch your `User` HABTM `Group` association. Either way you should then be able to access the data via [`AuthComponent::user()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3auser) from anywhere you want:

```
$currentUser = AuthComponent::user();
pr($currentUser['Group']);
```

---

**Edit (07.11.2012):** The problem with using `contain` in the authentication handler configuration is now [fixed for 2.2.4](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/3347), making it possible to pass `null` for the `recursive` setting.

Comment: Where do I insert that code? The only reference I found that seems fitting is within `AuthComponent.php`

Comment: This highly depends on your application, but generally it goes either in the `beforeFilter` callback of the controller where you are including the `Auth` component, or the settings are being passed directly to the `Auth` [component configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#configuring-components) in the `$components` property, see also [Configuring Authentication handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers).

Comment: Scratch that. I dropped it into `beforeFilter()` on `AppController.php` but still get no new fields on `AuthComponent::user()` while looking at it with `debug()`

Comment: Are you sure that the configuration is being used when logging in? Try passing the configuration in the `$components` property, and make sure that you are logging in again, otherwise it might use the old data stored in the session.

Comment: Still no go. I can access the Group array from `$this->Session->read('Auth')['Group'];` but not `AuthComponent::user()['Group']`. There is no 'Group' index on user().

Comment: If I put `$this->Session->write('Auth.User.Group',$this->Session->read('Auth')['Group']);` into my AppController.beforeFilter() I see the result I desire... strange?

Comment: Kinda strange yes, normally the data is being prepared in [`BaseAuthenticate::_findUser()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/bf628c493c1869c7c7d25d7298043e6b13f28179/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php#L96), it merges the results appropriately so that associations are available in the `userModel` result. Check if `_findUser()` actually returns the expected result.

Comment: Doesn't look like it is returning what I am after. Not sure what is causing this but I'm assuming the last dev on the project might have modified some of the core libraries instead of doing overrides. I really appreciate your help. I've got a functional working version now!